# PingPong by 1 pipe and 1 signal: what is scanf waiting for?

Tags: c, pipe, signals, fork

I've written PingPong on **C** by 1 signal and 1 pipe, so I need to send `pid1` to `son2` and `pid2` to `son1`, where `pid1`, `pid2` are pids of `son1`, `son2`.

But I see this picture:

```
Waiting..

PID: 4021

Waiting..
```

And I have this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int pidN;
int pid = -1;
int fd[2];
int max;

void SIGUSR1_hdl(int sig)
{
    // Set pid
    if (pid == -1) {
        printf("Waiting..\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &pid);
        printf("PID: %d\n", pid);
        fflush(stdout);
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        signal(SIGUSR1, SIGUSR1_hdl);
        return;
    }
    // Read x
    ..
    }

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, SIGUSR1_hdl);
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &max);
    pipe(fd);
    dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd[0]);

    int pid1;
    if (!(pid1 = fork())) {
        pidN = 1;
        for (;;) pause();
    }

    int pid2;
    if (!(pid2 = fork())) {
        pidN = 2;
        for (;;) pause();
    }

    kill(pid1, SIGUSR1);
    dprintf(fd[1], "%d\n%d\n%d\n", pid2, pid1, 1);
    close(fd[1]);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

It's hanging out before `scanf` in son2 in SIGUSR1_hdl. What am I doing wrong?
I can't inherit `pids` by a fork. I must only send it through my channel (fd).

Comment: `fflush()`,  `scanf()` and `printf()` are not guaranteed to be async signal save. They shall not be called from signal handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem (besides the signal unsafe functions you use) is that when `stdin` is connected to a non-terminal input it is *fully buffered*. That means when you attempt to read from `stdin` (which is what `scanf` does) it will attempt to fill the buffer as much as possible.

This means that a single child process will read *all* the data you've written into the pipe, leaving none for the other child process, which of course causes `scanf` to block infinitely.

Either you need to use two pipes, one for each child process, or some other way of synchronization between the processes.

Comment: Thank's a lot for an answer! You've helped me a lot.